# Outlook "Web Add-in" not appearing on Shared Mailbox, despite SupportsSharedFolders= True

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

we have this addin: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000060 This one on the store is working as expected.

As we need to support sharedinbox, we modified the manifest and we added:

```
<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
```

After the modification, we submited the manifest through the Exchange admin portal- integrated apps for all users

we assigned the following permission to the users:

- application Mail.Read
- Application Mail.ReadBasic
- Application Mail.ReadWrite
- Org Custom Apps
- Org Marketplace Apps
  this permissions were assigned to my personal user and to the shared mailbox

There are 2 ways to open the  shared folder
1- Clicking on your user profile, and select "Open another mailbox"
2- Right-clicking on your Folders, and select "Add shared mailbox"

for option 1: if we open the shared inbox on the online access (OWA) we  can see the addin but when you click on it, it does not perform any action, addin does not get triggered.
for option 2: addin is not displayed when selecting an email

If we open the shared inbox on the Outlook application, the addin is not visible

we also tested having a dedicated license to the shared inbox but didnt affect the result

Answer (score 2):

OWA supports add-ins in shared folders and does not support the same on shared mailboxes.
Win32 outlook supports both.

Comment: thank you for your reply. On our dev. account we created a shared inbox and we made the following test: 1- open the shared inbox on OWA and we can see the addin but when you click on it, it does not perform any action, addin does not get triggered. 2- we added the shared inbox on our outlook application (v 2203) and we cant even see the addin. We didnt see anything on the documentation where OWA is not supported, could you point out where this is documented? anyway, most of our customers use the outlook application, could you please help us?

Comment: You can find the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=modern under the section on Supported Setups.

Comment: we have double check and we meet the mentioned criterias, for example, on our developer account where we have a shared folder we are using the version 2204 with build 15128.20178 click-to-run over windows. We deployed the addin through the admin center, added the shared mailbox into our outlook aplication but the addin does not display. Is there an email where we can provide the modified manifest so we could check deeper? Thank you for your support!

Comment: Hello Microsoft team, I sent the manifest few days ago but I didnt get any reply, could you confirm you received the email with the manifest? Also, I would like to confirm that the email you will be running the manifest so we can configure it on our side. Thank you!

Comment: as for this document: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1877 we followed each step with personal folder and did not work neither, is there any update on your end please?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Outlook was this, and do you / your user use Outlook online?

The capability to work on Shared Mailboxes / Folders, is limited to Outlook versions that support Requirement Set 1.8 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows); which basically means Outlook must be Outlook 365 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview)

Comment: we use a developer account from Microsoft based on office 365. We tested on the  OWA access (Chrome) and also on the Outlook application Version 2203 (build 15028.20160 Click-to-run)

Comment: OK - so I checked and that Build is from end of March, so definitely after support for Shared Folders has been added.

Have you set the minimum feature set to 1.8 in the manifest?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview

Comment: We use 1.3 min requirements so it shuold be supported for our version        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>

Comment: Well, this should automatically support higher versions.

I really don't see why this works for some of your installations but not others.  

I guess it must be some configuration.  Hopefully the Outlook Add-in team fins the question and helps out.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook Add-in team says that support for shared mailbox is not available, yet in this support document it says that OWS supports API requirement set 1.8 which if I understood correctly is the requirment for shared Mailbox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview